# Format validation with lex and yacc

Tags: bison, yacc, flex-lexer, lex

Lets say I have a file containing strings like this:

```
qwerty01234xy+-/
rtweqq22222xx+++
```

The first 6 chars of [A-Z], then comes 5 of [0-9], then 2 of [A-Z] and at the end 3 of [+-/]. I would like to write a format checker, which yields syntax errors.
What I was doing till now, is something like this:

lex file:

```
<code>
...
/*states*/
%x WORD1_STATE
%x NUMBER_STATE
%x WORD22_STATE
%x ETC_STATE
%%
...
yy_push_state(ETC_STATE)
yy_push_state(WORD22_STATE)
yy_push_state(NUMBER_STATE)
yy_push_state(WORD1_STATE)
...
 /*rules*/
<WORD1_STATE>^[A-Z]{6}    yy_pop_state(); yylval.string=strdup(yytext); return WORD1;
<NUMBER_STATE>[0-9]{5}    yy_pop_state(); yylval.string=strdup(yytext); return NUMBER;
<WORD22_STATE>[A-Z]{2}    yy_pop_state(); yylval.string=strdup(yytext); return WORD2;
<ETC_STATE>[+-/]{3}    yy_pop_state(); yylval.string=strdup(yytext); return ETC;

\n        /*do nothing*/
<*>.      fprintf(stderr, "Bad character at line %d column %d: \"%s\"\n", yylloc.first_line, yylloc.first_column, yytext); yy_pop_state();
</code>
```

yacc rules:

```
<code>
 entries :
         | entry
         | error
         ;
 entry : WORD1 NUMBER WORD2 ETC;
</code>
```

My goal is the following: if this checker sees a line like this:

```
aaaaaa01W56ss--1
```

It yields the following error:

```
Bad character in NUMBER at line x at column 9
Bad character in ETC at line x at column 16
```

Is this the right direction? My code is not working of course. :)

Comment: You don't need either lex or yacc for this. Just a single regular expression.

Answer (score 2):

If you can predict the sequence of states perfectly enough to do it in your lexer, then there is really no point using `yacc`; it really doesn't provide any useful facilities here. (See below for an error recovery strategy in the lexer.) On the other hand, if the grammar is more complicated than a simple pattern sequence, you might need `yacc`; in that case, you should provide a more accurate example.

In any event, pushing the states on a stack is not a very efficient mechanism for handling the progression. It's usually easier to build a simple state machine with the `BEGIN` macro.

Here's the base lexer for your example:

```
%s NUMBER WORD2 ETC

%%
    /* Any indented text before the first rule is inserted
     * at the top of the yylex function.
     */
    int error_count = 0;
<INITIAL>[A-Z]{6} BEGIN(NUMBER);
<NUMBER>[0-9]{5}  BEGIN(WORD2);
<WORD2>[A-Z]{2}   BEGIN(ETC);
<ETC>[+-/]{3}     BEGIN(EOL);
<EOL>" "*\n       BEGIN(INITIAL);
<RECOVER>.*       BEGIN(EOL);
.|\n              signal_error(); ++error_count; BEGIN(RECOVER);
<<EOF>>           return error_count != 0;
```

(In (f)lex, the pattern `.` does not match a newline. The use of this fact in the `RECOVER` start condition should become apparent below.)

Keeping track of line and column information is easy as long as newlines are never part of a pattern, as in your example. So let's add that:

```
%s NUMBER WORD2 ETC

%%
    int error_count = 0;
    int line = 1, column = 1;
<INITIAL>[A-Z]{6} BEGIN(NUMBER);  column += yyleng;
<NUMBER>[0-9]{5}  BEGIN(WORD2);   column += yyleng;
<WORD2>[A-Z]{2}   BEGIN(ETC);     column += yyleng;
<ETC>[+-/]{3}     BEGIN(EOL);     column += yyleng;
<EOL>" "*\n       BEGIN(INITIAL); ++line; column = 0;
<RECOVER>.*       BEGIN(EOL);
.|\n              signal_error(); ++error_count; yyless(0); BEGIN(RECOVER);
<<EOF>>           return error_count;
```

(Note the use of `yyless(0)` in the default rule. This causes the errorneous character to be returned to the input source, so that it will be rescanned in the new start condition, which avoids some messy logic around newlines and getting the line and column counters correct. In addition, we centralize all newline handling in the `EOL` start condition's rule, in case we need to modify it later.)

Now it's only necessary to write the error reporter, for which we'll need to map states onto strings, and the `main` driver, and add what's necessary to avoid compiler warnings:

```
%{
#  include <stdio.h>

void signal_error(int state, int line, int column);
%}
%option noyywrap nounput noinput

%s NUMBER WORD2 ETC EOL RECOVER

%%
    int error_count = 0;
    int line=1, column=1;
<INITIAL>[A-Z]{6} BEGIN(NUMBER);  column += yyleng;
<NUMBER>[0-9]{5}  BEGIN(WORD2);   column += yyleng;
<WORD2>[A-Z]{2}   BEGIN(ETC);     column += yyleng;
<ETC>[+-/]{3}     BEGIN(EOL);     column += yyleng;
<EOL>" "*\n       BEGIN(INITIAL); ++line; column = 1;
<RECOVER>.*       BEGIN(EOL);
.|\n              { signal_error(YY_START, line, column);
                    ++error_count; yyless(0); BEGIN(RECOVER);
                  }
<<EOF>>           return error_count != 0;
%%

typedef struct { int state; const char* name; } StateToName;
const StateToName state_to_name[] = {
  { INITIAL, "in WORD1" },
  { NUMBER,  "in NUMBER"},
  { WORD2,   "in WORD2" },
  { ETC,     "in ETC"   },
  { EOL,     "at end of line"},
  { -1,      NULL}
};

const char* find_name(int state) {
  for (const StateToName* ent = state_to_name; ent->name; ++ent)
    if (state == ent->state) return ent->name;
  return "in unknown state";
}

void signal_error(int state, int line, int column) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Bad character %s at line %d, column %d\n",
                  find_name(state), line, column);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  return yylex();
}
```

This is still not quite as desired, because the reported column count is the start of the "token", rather than the actual column with an invalid character. Unfortunately, `flex` does not provide a way to write "match an initial prefix of this pattern." The pattern computation could be done manually in this case, but in general it's annoying:

```
<INITIAL>[A-Z]{6}   BEGIN(NUMBER);  column += yyleng;
<INITIAL>[A-Z]{0,5} BEGIN(ERROR);   column += yyleng;
<NUMBER>[0-9]{5}    BEGIN(WORD2);   column += yyleng;
<NUMBER>[0-9]{0,4}  BEGIN(ERROR);   column += yyleng;
<WORD2>[A-Z]{2}     BEGIN(ETC);     column += yyleng;
<WORD2>[A-Z]{0,1}   BEGIN(ERROR);   column += yyleng;
<ETC>[+-/]{3}       BEGIN(EOL);     column += yyleng;
<ETC>[+-/]{0,2}     BEGIN(ERROR);   column += yyleng;
```

With the above, it would be necessary to add `ERROR` to the list of start conditions, but since the start conditions are inclusive, there's no need to explicitly mark any rule for that condition.

Comment: Many thanks for the great explanation. One more thing I would like to have: what has to be done, to report multiple errors in one line? Currently if one error is identified, the next errors in the current line won't be "reported".

Answer (score 0):

For such simple checks (since you aren't showing a grammar) you won't need 'yacc'. If you don't really care about precise error messages you could write a 'grep' one-liner which filters out the wrong lines. If your motivation is to provide an error message, 'awk' is a neat solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

/[[:alpha:]]{6}[[:digit:]]{5}[[:alpha:]]{2}(+|-|\/)/ { next; }

{
    if (substr($0,1,6) !~ /[[:alpha:]]{6}/)
    print "first six chars in " NR, substr($0,1,6);
    # check for other mistakes
}
```

If it is lex/yacc knowledge you are after "Introduction to Compiling Techniques" by JP Bennett is a reasonably hands-on, albeit ancient, introduction.

Comment: The problem is, the code I showed is only a simplification, I have to deal with more tokens per line, and because of other features(like e.g. error messages, as you mentioned), "regex only" solutions are not appropriate. Anyway, thanks for the suggestion.